# Audacity, VLC package dependencies cannot be resolved? 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc, audacity

It was working, but suddenly disappeared from my pc and can't be installed again. VLC wont install either.

Ubuntu Software Centre gives these errors for Audacity:

```
audacity: Depends: audacity-data (= 2.0.5-1ubuntu3) but 2.0.5-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
          Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
          Depends: libflac++6 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
          Depends: libid3tag0 (>= 0.15.1b) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libportaudio2 (>= 19+svn20101113-2~) but 19+svn20140130-1 is to be installed
          Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but 2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but 2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

and these for VLC:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.2-2build2) but 2.1.2-2build2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Installing from the terminal returns the following errors respectively.

```
Audacity: The following packages have unmet dependencies. audacity : Depends: libflac++6 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not installable Depends: libid3tag0 (>= 0.15.1b) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. –  Erlja Jkdf. 1 min ago   edit
```

and

```
VLC: The following packages have unmet dependencies. vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.2-2build2) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not installable Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.2-2build2) but it is not going to be installed Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.2-2build2) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: what about `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 audacity : Depends: libflac++6 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libid3tag0 (>= 0.15.1b) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: That was for audacity. Vlc returns this: The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.2-2build2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.2-2build2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.2-2build2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` is meant to attempt to fix these issues. Do you use any PPAs? If it's still not working you need to go into 'Software & Updates' > 'Other Software' and uncheck or remove them. Then close the window, use `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get install audacity vlc` and, if they don't work, `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I removed all other software, and tried the commands, and still no joy.

Comment: Try this `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 ; sudo apt update ; sudo apt full-upgrade ; sudo apt-get install audacity vlc`

Comment: Still the same errors.

Comment: Updated it with some more details from the software centre.

Comment: for starters ck. one of the "not installable packages"  `apt-cache policy libid3tag0`

Comment: all i get is: libid3tag0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     0.15.1b-10ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trusted or accepted updates from all my extant PPA's, and what do you know, turns out i had blocked some of the ones necessary.